# Little help with JavaScript code involving setTimeout() method

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to understand two things about this code:

```
var updateFn = function(num){
   return function(){
      if(num == 6){
         console.info("100%, all items saved!")
      }
      else{
         var i = num/6;
         var pct = Math.round(100 * i);
         console.info(pct + "% saved");
      }
  };
};

for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++){
   setTimeout(updateFn(i), i * 500);
}
```

1. According to what i have read about setTimeout() syntax;

   ```
   setTimeout("javascriptstatement",milliseconds);
   ```

   So, why do I have to increment the milliseconds each loop till the total time until 500*6 ms?
   Why doesn't `setTimeout(updateFn(i), 500);` work as intended?
2. Why do I have to return a function for the function passed as the first parameter of
   setTimeout?

   Why doesn't this work?:

   ```
   var updateFn = function(num){
         if(num == 6){
            console.info("100%, all items saved!")
         }
         else{
            var i = num/6;
            var pct = Math.round(100 * i);
            console.info(pct + "% saved");
         }

   };

   for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++){
      setTimeout("updateFn(i)", i * 500);
   }
   ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may be an artifact of simplifying your code for posting, but why call setTimeout at all?  The function you are calling is not asynchronous, and since JS is single threaded, the only thing your setTimeouts will accomplish is delaying when the next function is called, and then only if the previous has finished (500ms is plenty for that call, but depending on what you are doing, it may not be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems it is setting 6 timeouts to occur every 500ms.  I think `setInterval` may be better here.
2. You want to return a function because if you pass a string to `setTimeout` it gets `eval`ed, and if you pass a function it just runs it.

It seems this code is making a progress meter for a save operation, though assuming the save will take 3 seconds, and incrementing the counter every 1/2 second may not be the best idea.

Anyway, instead of setting 6 timeouts, it would be better to use `setInterval`.

```
var updateFn = function(num){
  if(num == 6){
     console.info("100%, all items saved!");
     clearInterval(saving);
  }
  else{
     var i = num/6;
     var pct = Math.round(100 * i);
     console.info(pct + "% saved");
  }
};

var count = 1
var saving = setInterval(function(){
    updateFn(count++);
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(updateFn(i), 500);`  **works as intended** but probably not the way you'd hope it to work.

You are basically creating 6 timeouts which are executed at the exact same time (500 ms from now).

If you want them to be created 500ms apart from each other, then `setTimeout(updateFn(i), i * 500);` is the correct way to do it (or put `setTimeout(updateFn(i), 500);` inside of the `updateFn` function). If you want them to occur every 500ms you could also use `setInterval`.

Comment: I don't believe that is as intended - notice that you are are passing setTimeout the *result* of updatedFn(i).  You are calling it *right* away, not after the timeout.

Comment: @Matt I meant, that the logic behind the code is wrong, not a fault in how the code works. If he doesn't want it to work like that, should either call the remaining 5 timeouts within the actual updateFn function or use setInterval, as described in my answer.

Comment: My bad, I just now see he is returning a function with a call to updateFn(i)

Answer (score 0):

For 1: there is no reason (edit: no, there is: it postpones on execution 500ms after the other. As someone noted, setInterval is the way to go there), apparently: maybe the writer needs a way to simulate some "slowing down" effect in the fake saving function.

For 2: for setTimeout to work, you have NOT to return a function, but you DO have to for how that code is written: the first parameter of setTimeout is some code to be executed, and is quite standard to pass setTimeout a function (like an anonymous one). As in:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log("Hello world, 2 sec in the future");
}, 2000)
```