# Will this code cause a stack overflow? Javascript setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have the following code, and I was wondering if this will cause a stack overflow. I am not familiar with the way the setTimeout function is handled and its consequences.

```
function func1() {
    // some logic for the dynamicTimeout
    setTimeout("func2()", dynamicTimeout);
}

function func2() {
    // do something
    func1();
}
```

Comment: No, it won't. But then again, that's not your real code. You're creating a loop, and like any loop, you need to take care to not consume too much memory.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` schedules a function to be executed after a delay, and the "scheduler" function's stack isn't preserved, so a stack overflow will not occur directly due to the `setTimeout`.

In general, many browsers enforce a minimum timeout for functions scheduled this way (so even if you pass `0` as the timeout, or don't pass one at all, the function won't be scheduled immediately). Even if this isn't the case, the function gets added to a queue of waiting operations, and will be delayed if something else if executing.

As a side note, there's [no need to pass a string to `setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6232610/716118). It gets `eval`'d, which is sometimes insecure and generally slow. Better to just pass a function reference: `setTimeout(func2, dynamicTimeout)`.